# Does XIB always need a view controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

If I do an interface in `IB` must I always need a base `UIViewController` or can I just skip straight to a `UIView` ?

As of now I'm doing all my design in `obj-c` which makes for a bit more *busy work*.

If I have to use a `UIViewController` is there anyway to suck the `UIView` out of it if that's all I *want*?

I just want to be able to pull out *static layouts* from `XIB` instead of putting them together in `obj-c`.

Any suggestions are *appreciated*!

Comment: You want to just create the layout and have it in the XIB file?  Your second to last sentence was unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIViewController` has that handy `initWithNib: bundle:` method that makes everything so easy, but there are also ways to get objects from xibs via:

```
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"WhateverItsNamed" owner:self options:nil];
```

(and the nib array here contains objects which correspond to whatever objects are stored in the XIB file).

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need a UIViewController if it doesn't serve your needs.

After you have initialized a UINib, use its:

```
-instantiateWithOwner:options:
```

to access the nib contents.  Make the nib's root object be a UIView (or subclass thereof).  If you plan on making connections to File's Owner you will need to set File's Owner to a context-appropriate class.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to associate a `UIViewController` with a XIB.

First, do not add a view controller to the XIB. Then, you'd often use `NSNib` or `UINib` APIs to access the top level objects of the nib -- so you can avoid a view controller and set up any structure you'd like in the NIB editor, and programmatically access the objects in the NIB as needed.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 5, XIB are not recommended to be used anymore, you should use a storyboard instead.
And to simply answer your question, every top level view requires a view controller to be responsible for it.

All sub views can be an outlet in your view controller and be handled from there.

Comment: You can use nib/xib for non top-level views too, which I think is the OP's intent.  By splitting complex view hierarchies into multiple nibs you can dramatically reduce load times.